# liquibase migration scripts not executed in deploynodes

Tags: corda

I have 2 liquibase migration scripts in my `workflows/src/main/resources/migration` folder. When I run the `deployNodes` tasks it runs the schema migrations. However, it doesn't execute my scripts (tables are missing afterwards). I also tried to run the `run-migration-scripts --core-schemas --app-schemas` command manually, but still it doesn't execute the scripts. Any idea what can cause this behaviour? I am using corda 4.6.

I have also set `runSchemaMigration = true` in the gradle file.

Comment: Did you override getMigrationResource in your schema to specify the migration script name?

Comment: Oh, no. Maybe this was the missing hint. Thanks for the info, I will check it out and update my post.

Answer (score 0):

Ashutosh gave the same recommendation that I would have.

That getMigrationResource can be defined with something like this

```
public class IOUSchemaV1 extends MappedSchema {
    public IOUSchemaV1() {
        super(IOUSchema.class, 1, ImmutableList.of(PersistentIOU.class));
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getMigrationResource() {
        return "iou.changelog-master";
    }
```

source: https://www.corda.net/blog/cordapp-database-upgrade-migration-production-perspective/

for anyone finding this later, here's the doc page on it: https://api.corda.net/api/corda-os/4.6/html/api/javadoc/net/corda/core/schemas/CommonSchemaV1.html

Hopefully, that helps to solve the issue for you, good luck